# Solution to partial differential equation by separating variables

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Could someone please show me how to calculate this math problem?

By separating the variables, find the solution to the partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{1}{4} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}-u=0$$

in the area $x \ge 0$ with the boundary conditions

$$u(0, t)=\cos t, \quad \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow+\infty} u(x, t)=0$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question lacks context and your own attempt, and doesn’t meet many guidelines on this site. Please let us now specifically which part are you stuck on. What do you know about solving these equations in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this PDE is as follows
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{1}{4} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}-u=0
$$

and

$$
u(0, t)=\cos t, \quad \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow+\infty} u(x, t)=0
$$

The assumed solution is $u(x, t)=\xi(x)T(t)$ so that the PDE becomes
$$
\xi''(x)T(t)-\frac{1}{4}\xi(x)T''(t)-\xi(x)T(t)=0
$$
Then, to separate the variables rearrange to see that
$$
\frac{\xi''(x)}{\xi(x)}-\frac{T''(t)}{4T(t)}-1=0
$$
Next we realize that $\xi''(x)/\xi(x)$ and $T''(t)/T(t)$ must be constant because $x$ and $t$ are independent variables. We choose $T''(t)/T(t)=-\alpha^2$ to be negative because of the form of the boundary condition at $x=0$, and thus $\xi''(x)/\xi(x)=-\alpha^2/4+1$. This leads us to
$$
u(x, t)=\left(c_1 \sin\left(\frac{t}{\alpha}\right)+c_2\cos\left(\frac{t}{\alpha}\right)\right)\left(c_3 \exp\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-\alpha^2/4+1}}\right)+c_4\exp\left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{-\alpha^2/4+1}}\right)\right)
$$

Applying the BCs, we see that $\alpha=1$, $c_1=c_3=0$, $c_2c_4=1$, yielding the final solution
$$
u(x, t)=\cos(t)\exp\left(\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!